# Error in Displaying Routes - MapKit

Tags: ios, swift3, mapkit

This a part of my code. I'm trying to display some route between two points. Everything is working except for the routes.

> **[MKRoutePolyline interiorPolygons]**: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance

```
    let directionRequest = MKDirectionsRequest()
    directionRequest.source = sourceItem
    directionRequest.destination = destItem
    directionRequest.requestsAlternateRoutes = true
    directionRequest.transportType = .automobile

    let directions = MKDirections(request: directionRequest)
    directions.calculate(completionHandler: {
        response, error in
        guard let response = response else {
            if error != nil {
                print("Error")
            }
            return
        }
        let route = response.routes[0]
        self.mapView.add(route.polyline, level: .aboveRoads)

        let rekt = route.polyline.boundingMapRect
        self.mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(rekt), animated: true)
    })

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        let renderer = MKPolygonRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
        renderer.lineWidth = 5.0

        return renderer
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: i just edited my post

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: let says I have tried all that I know. It's too few so you could say that I have tried nothing.

Comment: Well normally on Stack Overflow you need to have tried something. Explaining what breakpoints you have set, where this code is failing, what research you have done beforehand, is critical to getting answers. Otherwise it looks like you put in no effort and you are asking us to do your work for you.

Comment: Considering that, I have tried looking for answers in youtube and sites that google provide. The exact point that my code is failing is in directions.calculate. I think it can't find a route or something but the destination is just on the next street.